# Eval vs web console

Tags: javascript, eval

I always hear and read "Eval is evil" if you evaluate user-generated code.

But where is the different from typing code into the web console? And what are the alternatives?

I know the web is full of questions like mine. But I wasn't able to understand what I read, I'm sorry. It would be great if you could help me. I remember I read something about scopes, so have eval() and the web console different scopes? If yes, why does that make the web console safer?

Thanks for your advice!
Darth Moon


Edit: Why is passing code through the web console / through eval dangerous at all? I though js will be executed client-side?

Comment: Typing code into the console is more evil than using `eval`. Though, if you know what you are using them for, then they are absolutely harmless.

Comment: Good point, code from the server should always get evaluated since it's mine. But what is with __user-generated__ javascript? Like if I have an online coding editor? How do I execute that code as safely as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Neither are safe to execute code in**; both can lead to XSS attacks.
The web console is just as vulnerable in this regard as eval'd code.

**However**, they do indeed have different scopes.

**[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** works in either the global scope or local scope depending on how it's invoked:

> If you use the eval function indirectly, by invoking it via a reference other than eval, as of ECMAScript 5 it works in the global scope rather than the local scope. This means, for instance, that function declarations create global functions, and that the code being evaluated doesn't have access to local variables within the scope where it's being called.

And the web console executes code in the page window scope.

What's interesting to note is that the **Browser Console** **[has a different scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)** to the **Web Console**, running under the browser's chrome window:

> Similarly, you can execute JavaScript expressions using the Browser Console. But while the Web Console executes code in the page window scope, the Browser Console executes them in the scope of the browser's chrome window.

Comment: But if the web console is as evil as eval, how do I avoid people typing bad code in the console?

Comment: Also the console provides more tool that are meant for debuging which makes typing code there a lot more evil than `eval`

Comment: @DarthMoon The oly person who can type code into the console is you. The console is evil only if you type code there that you don't understand, code that c.ould be malicious.

Comment: Thanks, this absolutely answers my question. I marked it as an accepted answer. However, I would like to know how to execute user-generated code as safely as possible and how to avoid people running bad code through the web console

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir What do you mean? __I__ am able to use the web console with _any_ website I want to. I even could pass js in the google.de page scope, it wan't be a big different since js is client-side and the code gets executed on my own device

Comment: @DarthMoon Possible scenario of how the console might be evil: you found online some code that's supposed to hack any facebook account, the poster of the code instruct you to open the web console on a facebook page that you want to hack and then copy-paste the code there and press enter. You read the code but didn't understand it, yet you did as told. The code is malicious and its poster posted it so people will be hacked if they did as told. Facebook even warns you from doing that [when you open the web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k6Is.png). Try opening it on a facebook page!

Comment: @DarthMoon Bottom line: if you don't know what you're typing into a web console, don't do it. If you don't know what you're passing to eval, don't do it. Also you can use `eval` to evaluate users code on the(ir) client-side. It absolutely their problem. They won't affect you in any way. If they are not carefull enough to just copy-paste code they don't understand into the web code editor on their computer, then its their problem if that code turns out to be malicious. You could add warnings and sanitize the code as much as you can, but it's their problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's a big different. So there's no way to "hack" my application with the web console if my server script (if I have one) doesn't exactly uses the javascript. I can't describe it better, so here's an example: I've got a multiplayer game. With js (and via Websockets) I told the server whenever I go and the server makes the move. That would be something like safe. But if js sent the exactly position I moved to, then every stupid nerd would be able to change his position with the web console. This means, if the server does all the important stuff, bad js won't affect me?

Comment: So I can understand that in general using eval() is not different than the console code? Any user can open the console and type whatever he/she wants... Right?